# `missing_scope` error when using `conversation.info` Slack API call

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am trying to retrieve slack channel name via slack bot token with channel id as a parameter.

The tester call works fine: `https://slack.com/api/conversations.info?token=<TOKEN>&channel=C0000000000&pretty=1(open raw response)`

However, when trying from webhook script it returns the following error only when accessing channel:

```
"err":{
"message":"An API error occurred: missing_scope",
"name":"Error",
"stack":"Error: An API error occurred: missing_scope\n
    at Object.platformErrorFromResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/errors.js:50:33)\n
    at WebClient.apiCall (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@slack/web-api/dist/WebClient.js:485:28)\n
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
...
```

I believe that `channels:read` permission have been granted.